# How to run only one role of an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

I have a site.yml which imports several playbooks.

```
- import_playbook: webservers.yml
- ....
```

Every playbook "calls" several roles:

```
- name: apply the webserver configuration 
  hosts: webservers

  roles:
  - javajdk
  - tomcat
  - apache
```

**How can I run only the javajdk role ?**

This would run all roles... 
`ansible-playbook -i inventory  webservers.yml`

I know that there are **tags**, but how do I assign them to a role in general?

Answer (score 22):

Tags are natural way to go. Three ways of specifying them for roles below:

```
- name: apply the webserver configuration 
  hosts: webservers

  roles:
    - role: javajdk
      tags: java_tag
    - { role: tomcat,  tags: tomcat_tag }

  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: apache
      tags: apache_tag
```

You can explictly specify the tags to run:

```
ansible-playbook example.yml --tags "java_tag"
```

<sup>[Reference to docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tags.html)</sup>

Comment: This will either define a tag on the task level, what is to granular or at the place where a role is *used* but this will not generally assign the tag to the role. In case the role is used in an other playbook it will *not* have the tag. Of cause this are two separate approaches, just hope that the genearl one is also possible

Comment: Frankly speaking, I have no clue what you wanted to say in your comment.

Comment: Sorry for my unclearness,  frankly, I will try it again. Your answer is works fine when I look at the above example. Now step back and imagine a second playbook which also uses  - role: javajdk (no tag) Logically for this second  playbook will not work with a tag-filter.   -- The question is now can a tag be assigned to a role (only one time, one place) so that a filter on tag will work. The only advantage would be to avoid to assign tags to a role every time it is used.

Comment: I understand now what you say. Fortunately (!) you can't achieve it easily.

Comment: An example of how to run `ansible-playbook` with tags would make this a better answer.

Comment: @JustinW.Flory is this what you are referring to? ansible-playbook example.yml --tags "configuration,packages"